# pyodbc exports a csv file full with header names instead of data reconds

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pyodbc

I am trying to figure out why when I export a database view from a MSSQL database it results in a csv file which only contains the view's header columns. For example, that is the resulting file that I am currently getting:

```
"",""
"RIG ID","Date - Rig"
"RIG ID","Date - Rig"
"RIG ID","Date - Rig"
...
```

That is the export code that I am running:

```
import csv
import os
import pyodbc

# Rig db Params/Vars
# Rigs data csv file path and name.
filePath = os.getcwd() + '/'
fileName = 'export.csv'
...

# SQL to select data from the rigs table.
rigs_export_sql = "SELECT TOP 10 'RIG ID', 'Date - Rig' FROM schema_name.view_name"

def export_rigs_data():
    
    # Database connection variable.
    connect = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                                     server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)
    
    # Cursor to execute query.
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    
    # Execute query.
    cursor.execute(rigs_export_sql)
    
    # Fetch the data returned.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    
    # Extract the table headers.
    headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    
    # Open CSV file for writing.
    csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                        delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')
    
    # Add the headers and data to the CSV file.
    csvFile.writerow(headers)
    csvFile.writerows(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    export_rigs_data()
```

What I am missing?

**Note**: when I execute the the following query `"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM schema_name.view_name` I am getting all of the data and header fine

Comment: Seems like `SELECT TOP 10 'RIG ID', 'Date - Rig'` is selecting the same string literals for each row - that's why the first line is empty strings, because there are no column names. Maybe you meant to try `SELECT TOP 10 [RIG ID], [Date - Rig]`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried your suggestion but now I am getting a blank file :/

Comment: So what are the actual column names in `schema_name.view_name` that you're trying to select? If you're trying to rename them for appearance's sake in the CSV file then you need to use something like `SELECT TOP 10 [Foo] as [RIG ID], [Bar] as [Date - Rig] ...`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the strange thing is that those are the actual names of the view columns that I am trying to select. For simplicity sake, I tried `SELECT top 10 [RIG ID] FROM schema_name.view_name` but that produced an empty file with nothing in there